# VB.NET - Strange behavior - Timer would not start

Tags: vb.net, timer, error-handling

When I connect the background colors are changing to "SpringGreen" and when an Wxeption occurs they change to "Yellow", the message box appears ("Timer on") and the background colors are changing to "Gray"????

But whenan Exeption occurs at ReceiveMessag() the colors are changing to "Yellow" and the debug line displays that trmReboot is enabled, but no message box and the background colors are not changing to "Gray"????

Why would the timer not start with the ReceiveMessag() Exeption??

```
 Private Sub Connect()
    Try
        _client = New TcpClient(strIP, intPort)
        Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf ReceiveMessages)
        Try
            If _client.Connected Then
                login()
                tsStatusIP.BackColor = Color.SpringGreen
                tsStatusIPport.BackColor = Color.SpringGreen
                tsStatusIP.Text = "IP adres: " + strIP
                tsStatusIPport.Text = "Server poort nummer: " + intPort.ToString
                booConnected = True
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            'MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    Catch ex As Exception
        ExecptionHandler()
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub ReceiveMessages(state As Object)
    Try
        While True
            Dim ns As NetworkStream = _client.GetStream()

            Dim toReceive(100000) As Byte
            ns.Read(toReceive, 0, toReceive.Length)
            Dim txt As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(toReceive)
            messagerecieved(txt)

            '  If Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of frmReceivedData).Any = True Then 'check if form is open
            If txtReceivedData.Visible = True Then
                txtReceivedData.Text = txtReceivedData.Text + txt
            End If
            '  End If
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        ExecptionHandler()
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub ExecptionHandler()
    tsStatusIP.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    tsStatusIPport.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    booConnected = False
    tmrReboot.Enabled = True
    Debug.Print(tmrReboot.Enabled)
End Sub
Private Sub tmrReboot_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrReboot.Tick
    MsgBox("timer on")
    tsStatusIP.BackColor = Color.Gray
    tsStatusIPport.BackColor = Color.Gray
End Sub
```

Comment: That is very bad code I'm afraid.  You start a new thread and then you do all sorts of foreground work on that thread.  If you want to affect the UI then you should be doing so ONLY on the UI thread.  WinForms Timers are intended to work ONLY on the UI thread.  You need to separate all the background work from the foreground work and do the foreground work only on the UI thread.

Comment: Hi jmcihinney, Thank you for your respond.
Can you explain a bit more or maybe give an example?

Comment: Here's one I prepared earlier: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?498387-Accessing-Controls-from-Worker-Threads

Comment: Note that the vbforums site seems to be struggling at the moment for some reason, so you may have an issue getting to that example of mine right now.

Comment: Tnx, I will have a look at it.